# SQL, On delete cascade and on update cascade

Tags: sql, oracle, cascade

I am new to SQL and I encountered a weird problem. So I have two tables OFFERS and
SUPPLIER. Here is the Supplier table.

```
CREATE TABLE  "SUPPLIER" 
   (    "S#" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50),  
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(50), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("S#") ENABLE
   )
```

And here is the OFFERS table.

```
CREATE TABLE  "OFFERS" 
   (    "P#" NUMBER, 
    "S#" NUMBER, 
    "V#" NUMBER, 
    "PR#" NUMBER, 
      CONSTRAINT "PK_OFFERS" PRIMARY KEY ("P#") ENABLE
   )
```

So now, when I try to add a Foreign key constraint to the offers table like this

```
ALTER TABLE OFFERS
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIERS FOREIGN KEY(S#)
 REFERENCES SUPPLIER (S#) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I get an error saying : "ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option". If I remove the last line, which is "ON UPDATE CASCADE" this works perfectly fine. So, what am I doing wrong? I've seen a lot of examples like this on the internet, that are supposed to work, so I am kinda confused. I am working on apex.oracle.com if that makes any difference.

Comment: If everything else fails read the instructions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#CJAIHHGC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "on update cascade" in Oracle as far as I know (even in current versions):

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034

Comment: is there an equivalent feature/workaround available, other than the obvious "drop the constraints, fix the values and put the constraints back"?

Comment: You don't need to drop it, you can disable it and turn it on. The best solution is to use deferred constraints, what will happen in this case- when executing the transaction you won't get errors- all the deferred constraints checking would happen on commit- and if you did all the required changes, it will behave the way you expect it to.

Comment: Check out this link - might help http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0120__Table/DeferredConstraints.htm